# How do i access d3 element dom data?

Tags: d3.js

I have a page that has these elements:

```
<svg version="1.1" class="chart avg@i"  data-href='[{"name": "ken", "age": "40"}]'></svg>
```

... later on

```
<svg version="1.1" class="chart avg@i"  data-href='[{"name": "Jen", "age": "40"}]'></svg>
```

What I really want is for this data to be put in a chart, admittedly a very boring chart. So to that end I have:

```
var chart = d3.selectAll(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

So I will get two charts (I mean, there is more d3 stuff, but you get the idea). What i want is to populate the chart data *with the data from the href in the particular element that the chart is for*.

How do i do this? To be clear, I want one "ken" chart, and one, different, "Jen" chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to collect data-href attribute from each SVG and create charts inside that SVG using the same data.

Hope this code snippet helps.

```js
var width = 200,
  height = 200,
  margin = {
    left: 5,
    right: 5,
    top: 5,
    bottom: 5
  };
var chart = d3.selectAll(".chart")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

chart.each(function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("data-href"));
  d3.select(this)
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", function(d, i){ return (i+1)+"em" })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name
    });
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" class="chart avg@i" data-href='[{"name": "ken", "age": "40"},{ "name": "Alan", "age": 15 }]'></svg>
<svg version="1.1" class="chart avg@i" data-href='[{"name": "Jen", "age": "40"}]'></svg>
```

Comment: you've set me off on a better track, but it seems that the data array has *all* the data, so that each chart uses all the data - i would like the chart to only use the data pertinent to that chart

Comment: Hi Bharal, I have updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: words cannot express how grateful I am. You are a champion, thankyou.